# Use MPI gather to get data from tasks into master array

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I'm learning how to use MPI to calculate the 4 point stencil of a 2d hot plate. But my issue is that when writing my results to an output file, the output file only contains the results of one of the tasks (I believe its the task that finishes first). What I want to do is gather the data after performing all the iterations in the worker tasks back to the master, but I am unsure how to do that. I want to use MPI_Gather, or believe I need to use it, but I don't quite understand how to do it from the tutorials.

Alternatively, am I misallocating how to return data back to the master in my worker threads?

Code here:

```cpp
#define BEGIN       1                  /* message tag */
#define LTAG        2                  /* message tag */
#define RTAG        3                  /* message tag */
#define NONE        0                  /* indicates no neighbor */
#define DONE        4                  /* message tag */
#define MASTER      0                  /* taskid of first process */
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;



void update(int start, int end, int ny, double* u1, double* u2)
{
    int ix, iy;
    for (ix = start; ix <= end; ix++)
    {
        for (iy = 1; iy <= ny - 2; iy++)
        {
            //calculate stencil
            *(u2 + ix * ny + iy) = .25 * (
                *(u1 + (ix + 1) * ny + iy) +
                *(u1 + (ix - 1) * ny + iy) +
                *(u1 + ix * ny + (iy + 1)) +
                *(u1 + ix * ny + (iy - 1)));
        }


    }

    //pass into buffer
    for (ix = start; ix <= end; ix++)
        for (iy = 1; iy <= ny - 2; iy++)
            *(u1 + ix * ny + iy) = *(u2 + ix * ny + iy);

}



bool isNumber(char number[])
{
    int i = 0;

    //checking for negative numbers
    if (number[0] == '-')
        return false;
    for (; number[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        //if (number[i] > '9' || number[i] < '0')
        if (!isdigit(number[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //variable init
    int N = 0;
    int I = 0;
    int taskid,                     /* this task's unique id */
        numworkers,                 /* number of worker processes */
        numtasks,                   /* number of tasks */
        averow, rows, offset, extra,   /* for sending rows of data */
        dest, source,               /* to - from for message send-receive */
        left, right,        /* neighbor tasks */
        msgtype,                    /* for message types */
        rc, start, end,               /* misc */
        i, ix, iy, iz, it;              /* loop variables */
    MPI_Status status;

    //There should be five arguments, no more no less
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid parameters, please check your values." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!isNumber(argv[2]) || !isNumber(argv[4]))
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid parameters, please check your values." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //check the n flag in either valid position. 
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-n"))
    {
        N = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(argv[3], "-n"))
    {
        N = atoi(argv[4]);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid flags, please check your values." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //check the I flag in either valid position
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-I"))
    {
        I = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(argv[3], "-I"))
    {
        I = atoi(argv[4]);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid flags, please check your values." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if (N == 0 || I == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid parameters, please check your values." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    int n_x = N + 2; //Based on the piazza post, increase x and y dimension by two for the edges
    int n_y = N + 2;
    double** phi[2];
    double** resultArray;
    phi[0] = new double* [n_x];
    phi[1] = new double* [n_x];
    resultArray = new double* [n_x];
    for (int i = 0; i < n_x; i++)
    {
        phi[0][i] = new double[n_y];
        phi[1][i] = new double[n_y];
        resultArray[i] = new double[n_y];
    }
    int iterationMax = I;
    //Initialize the plate temperatures
    for (int j = 0; j < n_x; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_x; i++)
        {
            if ((i == 0) || (i == n_x - 1) || (j == 0) || (j == n_y - 1))
            {
                phi[0][i][j] = 20.0;
                phi[1][i][j] = 20.0;
            }
            else
            {
                phi[0][i][j] = 0.0;
                phi[1][i][j] = 0.0;
            }


        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n_x; j++)
    {
        if (j > (int)(0.3 * n_x) && j < (int)(0.7 * n_x))
        {

            phi[0][0][j] = 100.0;
            phi[1][0][j] = 100.0;
        }
    }



    /* First, find out my taskid and how many tasks are running */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);
    numworkers = numtasks - 1;
    if (taskid == 0) {
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

        /************************* master code *******************************/
        /* Check if numworkers is within range - quit if not */

        //printf("Starting mpi_heat2D with %d worker tasks.\n", numworkers);

        /* Initialize grid */
        //printf("Grid size: X= %d  Y= %d  Time steps= %d\n", n_x, n_y, I);


        /* Distribute work to workers.  Must first figure out how many rows to */
        /* send and what to do with extra rows.  */
        averow = n_x / numworkers;
        extra = n_x % numworkers;
        offset = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= numworkers; i++)
        {
            rows = (i <= extra) ? averow + 1 : averow;
            /* Tell each worker who its neighbors are, since they must exchange */
            /* data with each other. */
            if (i == 1)
                left = 0;
            else
                left = i - 1;
            if (i == numworkers)
                right = 0;
            else
                right = i + 1;
            /*  Now send startup information to each worker  */
            dest = i;
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&left, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&right, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&phi[0][offset][0], rows * n_y, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, 1,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            /* printf("Sent to task %d: rows= %d offset= %d ", dest, rows, offset);
             printf("left= %d right= %d\n", left, right);*/
            offset = offset + rows;
        }
        /* Now wait for results from all worker tasks */
        for (i = 1; i <= numworkers; i++)
        {
            source = i;
            msgtype = DONE;
            MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                &status);
            MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&phi[0][offset][0], rows * n_y, MPI_DOUBLE, source,
                msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }


        /* Write final output, call X graph and finalize MPI */

        auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start);

        std::cout.precision(5);
        // output the time to the console
        std::cout << "Time taken to solve diffusion plate: " << duration.count() << "ms" << std::fixed << std::endl;

    }   /* End of master code */

    /************************* workers code **********************************/
    if (taskid != MASTER)
    {

        /* Receive my offset, rows, neighbors and grid partition from master */
        source = MASTER;
        msgtype = BEGIN;
        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&left, 1, MPI_INT, source, msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&right, 1, MPI_INT, source, msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&phi[0][offset][0], rows * n_y, MPI_DOUBLE, source, msgtype,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        /* Determine border elements.  Need to consider first and last columns. */
        /* Obviously, row 0 can't exchange with row 0-1.  Likewise, the last */
        /* row can't exchange with last+1.  */
        start = offset;
        end = offset + rows - 1;
        if (offset == 0)
            start = 1;
        if ((offset + rows) == n_x)
            end--;
        // printf("task=%d  start=%d  end=%d\n", taskid, start, end);

         /* Begin doing STEPS iterations.  Must communicate border rows with */
         /* neighbors.  If I have the first or last grid row, then I only need */
         /*  to  communicate with one neighbor  */
         //printf("Task %d received work. Beginning time steps...\n", taskid);
        iz = 0;
        for (it = 1; it <= iterationMax; it++)
        {
            if (left != NONE)
            {
                MPI_Send(&phi[iz][offset][0], n_y, MPI_DOUBLE, left,
                    RTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                source = left;
                msgtype = LTAG;
                MPI_Recv(&phi[iz][offset - 1][0], n_y, MPI_DOUBLE, source,
                    msgtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            }
            if (right != NONE)
            {
                MPI_Send(&phi[iz][offset + rows - 1][0], n_y, MPI_DOUBLE, right,
                    LTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                source = right;
                msgtype = RTAG;
                MPI_Recv(&phi[iz][offset + rows][0], n_y, MPI_DOUBLE, source, msgtype,
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            }
            /* Now call update to update the value of grid points */
            update(start, end, n_y, &phi[iz][0][0], &phi[1-iz][0][0]);
            iz = 1 - iz;
        }
        /* Finally, send my portion of final results back to master */
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&phi[iz][offset][0], rows * n_y, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, DONE,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        //printf("Task %d finished work...\n", taskid);
        MPI_Finalize();
    }

    //This is probably not correct
    /*double gsize;
    int root, myrank;
    double* mybuf;

    MPI_Gather(&mybuf, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, phi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);*/

    std::ofstream outJob;
    outJob.open("finalTemperatures.csv");
    std::cout.precision(15);
    double* printAddr = &phi[0][0][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < n_y; j++) //file IO
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_x; i++)
        {
            outJob << phi[0][j][i] << "," << std::fixed;
        }
        outJob << std::endl;
    }
    outJob.close();


    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: the same file is written by all the ranks, so that cannot work. One option is to gather all the data on a rank, and then write it all **from that rank**

Comment: The for loop at the end of the master thread loops through the worker ranks and pushes the data to master. Is that not what you mean?

Comment: In this case, only the master should write to file.